# how can i wrap my script with other codes in a div with a class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script and 2 divs that work fine and are in their place.

But I want them all to be in the header and when I wrap the whole code in a the header div it does not work properly.

The image produced by the script is placed after the divs and I can not give my header a class... how can I do that? Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30); // 0...6

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.className = "logo";

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "images/gifs/"+num+".gif";

link.appendChild(img).setAttribute("class", "logo");
document.body.appendChild(link);

</script>

<div class="padding-title">                    
    <a href="index.html">

        <p class="small">
            <font face="courier" size="4">
                <h1>heading</h1>
            </font>
        </p>

        <p class="small2">
            <font face="courier" size="4">
                -<br>
                L1LINE<br>
                L2
            </font>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>         

<div class="menu2">
    <font face="courier" size="4">
        <p class="small3">
            <a href="m1.html" class="small3">M1</a>                    
            <a href="m2.html" class="small3">M2</a>
            <a href="m3.html" class="small3">M3</a>
         </p>
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: Look for `:before` and `:after` pseudoclasses.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i can't understand how to use it for the script as it is not a paragraph or something...

Comment: What about: `insertBefore()`

Comment: as i see insertBefor() does the arrangement between variables. in here i need to put the script result befor a div.